# How do I find all documents in mongodb collection that contain field/value pair?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database in mongodb with many documents that all are formatted the same as the following example document:

```
{
  "_id": "1234567",
  "data groups": {
    "group1": [
      {
        "clientname": "client1",
        "companyname": "company1",
        "data": {
          "item one": {
            "item name": "items full name",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "clientname": "client2",
        "companyname": "company2",
        "data": {
          "item one": {
            "item name": "items full name",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "group2": [
      {
        "clientname": "client1",
        "companyname": "company1",
        "data": {
          "subgroup76": {
            "item name": "item name 1",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          },
          "subgroup77": {
            "item name": "item name 2",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          },
          "subgroup10": {
            "item name": "item name 3",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          },
          "subgroup8": {
            "item name": "item name 4",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "clientname": "client2",
        "companyname": "company2",
        "data": {
          "subgroup6": {
            "item name": "item name 1",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          },
          "subgroup5": {
            "item name": "item name 2",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          },
          "subgroup8": {
            "item name": "item name 3",
            "bool1": false,
            "bool2": false,
            "infofield": "info value"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to query the database to find all documents that contain a value of true in bool1 or bool2 anywhere within the document.  I assume this is possible but I have so far been unable to figure it out.  Does anyone more familiar with mongodbs query language know how I would do this?

I tried multiple querys using db.dbname.find() but all of my attempts resulted in errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but I don't know of a simple way.  I wish MongoDB had more `jq`-like operators, or I was good enough at javascript to recreate `jq`-like operators.

This `"$match"` is "field name agnostic", except for `"data groups"` (the head), `"bool1"`, and `"bool2"` (the leaves).  Although, the pipeline is dependent on the constant structure/depth of the `bool` fields.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {"$objectToArray": "$data groups"},
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": {
            "$or": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$anyElementTrue": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$$this.v",
                    "as": "v",
                    "in": {
                      "$reduce": {
                        "input": {"$objectToArray": "$$v.data"},
                        "initialValue": false,
                        "in": {"$or": ["$$value", "$$this.v.bool1", "$$this.v.bool2"]}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fOspZf2nc2K).